# Brew cleanup removed latest python version?

Tags: homebrew

I was installing imagemagick, and it ran a cleanup since it had not been done for 30 days, and it removed a bunch of stuff, including:

```
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gdbm... (64B)

Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python... (3 files, 148.3KB)

Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/readline... (64B)

Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/sqlite... (64B)

Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/xz... (64B)

Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gettext... (64B)

Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/pcre2... (64B)

Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openssl@1.1... (64B)

Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/git... (64B)
```

when I type python it says 2.7.10
Is it normal for the cleanup to remove ^^ or is it just removing junk like cached stuff?

I am learning coding right now and have no clue what I ventured into, was just trying to append images.

Comment: It removed log files it created in the past during the update of some packages. Nothing important. Those listed as having 64B are empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

It removed the contents of `~/Library/Logs`, which are generally only useful if you have an issue with a program and know where to look.

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/272933):

> Yes, log files can be safely deleted. Next time a log file needs to be appended to and is missing, it will be created (don't delete the actual Logs folder itself though). Log files are always presumed transient. However, before you delete all your log files, it might be worth keeping the most recent content of the most important log files in case you need to troubleshoot any problems.

Comment: Which is not to say homebrew doesnt run chaos over python installs from time to time. It can be... somewhat annoying.

Folks, learn virtualenv or one of its variants (or conda, though I dont know much about that)